# Are any optimization passes available in Fable?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I wrote the following code in the [Fable REPL](https://fable.io/repl/):

```ml
open Fable.Core

let inline sqr x = x * x

// Filters out `points` that are more than `radius` away
let inRadius radius points = 
  points
  |> List.filter (fun (x, y) -> sqr x + sqr y <= sqr radius)
```

And the output JavaScript was:

```js
import { filter } from "fable-library/List.js";

export function inRadius(radius, xs) {
  return filter(function predicate(tupledArg) {
    return tupledArg[0] * tupledArg[0] + tupledArg[1] * tupledArg[1] <= radius * radius;
  }, xs);
}
```

More optimal JavaScript would be:

```js
import { filter } from "fable-library/List.js";

export function inRadius(radius, xs) {
  const radiusSquared = radius * radius; 

  return filter(function predicate(tupledArg) {
    return tupledArg[0] * tupledArg[0] + tupledArg[1] * tupledArg[1] <= radiusSquared;
  }, xs);
}
```

*(This is just one example of an optimization that might be applied, there are many more possibilities)*

In JavaScript it is hard to safely make this optimization because of the lack of types. However, in the original F# code we know the type of `radius` so we *can* safely make this optimization. To me this seems like a big advantage of Fable over JavaScript.

However, such optimizations need to actually be implemented somewhere.

- Is it possible to enable optimizations like this in Fable?
- If not, are there other tools that can perform such optimizations?

Comment: Are you sure that this optimisation is performed even running F# under .NET?

Comment: @MarkPattison I am not sure that it is. However, given how much faster .NET can be than most JavaScript run-times it is particularly important for my Fable use-cases

Answer (score 6):

I would expect from Fable or any other transpiler to preserve the structure of the code. So you could optimize your F# code to calculate radius^2 only once.

```
open Fable.Core

let inline sqr x = x * x

// Filters out `points` that are more than `radius` away
let inRadius radius =
    let radiusSqr = sqr radius
    List.filter (fun (x, y) -> sqr x + sqr y <= radiusSqr)
```